# Java How to access hash map data held in an array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

learning Java and have figured out how to store a hashmap in an array. But I can't figure out how to get to the stored data. Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing. I've got as far as displaying the specific array items, but how do I access the hash map stored in the array?

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> custOrder = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List ordersPlaced = new ArrayList();

    custOrder.put("colour", "blue");
    custOrder.put("manu", "bmw");
    custOrder.put("body", "4x4");

    ordersPlaced.add(custOrder);

    custOrder = new HashMap();

    custOrder.put("colour", "green");
    custOrder.put("manu", "merc");
    custOrder.put("body", "saloon");

    ordersPlaced.add(custOrder);   


    System.out.println(ordersPlaced.get(0).toString());
  }
}
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance

Neil

Comment: Note that an `ArrayList` is **not the same** as an array. Please don't use **raw-types**, always specify which type your classes should hold, so `List<...>` and not just `List`. Same for the second `HashMap`. You access elements of an `ArrayList` by using the `get` method like you did in your demo, where exactly is the problem?

Comment: `ordersPlaced.get(0)` is how you get the first element (which is the map). The string you're seeing is the default implementation of `toString` defined in the `Object` class. If you want to print "key, value" pairs, iterate on the result.

Comment: If you want to interact with the map you may use `get(key)` like `custOrder.get("colour")`, it will return `"green"`.

Comment: Could you have a brief example Zabuza please. That's what I would like to know how to access the colour of the data stored in the array at location 0 for example Maroun. Thanks

Comment: Zabuza, I understand that, but I then store the map in an array. How to I interact with the maps that are stored in the ordersPlaced array? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know it already.

You can get back the stored map by writing

```
Map<String, String> placedCustOrder = ordersPlaced.get(0);
```

And avoid using raw types while using List. Declare your list as

```
List<Map<String, String>> ordersPlaced = new ArrayList<>();
```

> I would like to know how to access the colour of the data stored in the array at location 0

Since you got the map as I said in the line 1

```
Map<String, String> placedCustOrder = ordersPlaced.get(0);
String colorVal = placedCustOrder.get("colour");
```

I strongly suggest you to look through `Map` documentation before proceeding further.

Comment: Excellent many thanks. Well go back and look at maps, array etc.

Answer (score 4):

You're already accessing it.

In order to get the iterate on the map's items, you can:

```
ordersPlaced.get(0).forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println("Key is: " + key + ", Value is: " + value);
});
```

Or, earlier to Java 8, something like:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : ordersPlaced.get(0).entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Please note that you should avoid using raw type list. Instead, you should have:

```
List<Map<String, String>> ordersPlaced = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then:

```
Map<String, String> m = ordersPlaced.get(0);
```